# Proper use of curl_multi to make parallel asynchronous calls

Tags: php, curl

I found a [simple class](https://gist.github.com/Xeoncross/2362936) to do a parallel requests:

```
class Requests {
    public $handle;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->handle = curl_multi_init();
    }
    public function process($urls, $callback) {
        foreach($urls as $url) {
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt_array($ch, array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE));
            curl_multi_add_handle($this->handle, $ch);
        }
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($this->handle, $active);
            if ($state = curl_multi_info_read($this->handle)) {
                $info = curl_getinfo($state['handle']);
                $callback(curl_multi_getcontent($state['handle']), $info);
                curl_multi_remove_handle($this->handle, $state['handle']);
            }
            usleep(10000); // stop wasting CPU cycles and rest for a couple ms
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $active);
    }
    public function __destruct() {
        curl_multi_close($this->handle);
    }
}
```

This should be used in the following way:

```
$dataprocess = function($data,$info){
  echo $data;
}
$urls = array('url1','url2','url3');
$rqs = new Requests();
$rqs->process(urls,$dataprocess);
```

However it looks like not all urls are fetching (I'd estimate that only about a half of urls are fetched).

I found [this note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php#80977) to PHP's curl_multi_exec [function description](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php):

*If it returns CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM you better call it again soon, as that is a signal that it still has local data to send or remote data to receive.*

So I suspect that this class returns too earlier or should repeat the request in some cases. But the class is controlling both `curl_multi_exec` output and `$active` parameter, so it should work fine.

Any thoughs?

**UPDATE**

What I've done for the moment is that I put a cicle in the function `process` around all its code to execute it until all the URL's are retrieved (during debugging I see that after each iteration the number of unloaded URLs is reducing like 50-22-8-0).

But I changed the class dramatically: instead of a callback function I'm passing the array with two key names (one for URL and one for content storing). So it working for me now but I still can not figure out how to do this for callback function style.